# Android crashes when looping through a string array [Android Studio]

Tags: android, arrays, string

I am trying to filter out specific strings in an array with the following code, but it keeps crashes when I try to run it.

```
public String[] lister(String[] fl){
    String[] filelist = {};
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < fl.length; i++){
        if (fl[i].contains("Incident ")){
            filelist[j] = fl[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return filelist;
}
```

I already tried some things, and it seems to be that

```
filelist[j] = fl[i];
```

is the culprit.
When I run

```
public String[] lister(String[] fl){
    String[] filelist = {};
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < fl.length; i++){
        if (fl[i].contains("Incident ")){
            //filelist[j] = fl[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    filelist = fl;
    return filelist;
}
```

It doesn't crash, even though it runs the forloop. Obviously the result is not what I need.

I don't understand why it does this? For some reason it feels as if it doesn't see 'filelist' initialized in the forloop.

Comment: You are trying to declare an array of unknown length which is not possible. Use `ArrayList` instead or give your array a fixed length.

Comment: What is happening that is not expected?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of array use `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> filelist = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < fl.length; i++){
    if (fl[i].contains("Incident ")){
        filelist.add(fl[i]);
    }
}
return filelist;
```

Comment: @Cer If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted (Also consider other answers and mark the best one as accepted).

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto fair enough :D

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to declare an array of unknown length, arrays are constant in length. Its better to use `java.util.List` implementation like `ArrayList` or `List`.

Or give your array a size like

```
String[] filelist = new String[3];
```

**Solution 1: Using ArrayList**

```
public String[] lister(String[] fl){
    List<String> filelist = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < fl.length; i++){
        if (fl[i].contains("Incident ")){
            filelist.add(fl[i]);
        }
    }
    return filelist;
}
```

**Solution 2: Giving array a fixed length (Useful only if you know the length already)**

```
public String[] lister(String[] fl){
    String[] filelist = new String[3]; // or any size
    for(int i = 0; i < fl.length; i++){
        if (fl[i].contains("Incident ")){
            filelist[i] = fl[i];
        }
    }
    return filelist;
}
```

**Note:** Variable `j` is not really required

Answer (score 0):

That's because the length of the variable `filelist` is **0**, as you give no values `{}`, so you are getting [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) as `filelist[j]` will always exceed the array bounds whatever the value of `j` is, so you have to define it like the following:

```
String[] filelist = new String[fl.length];
```